# Apache server unresponsive due to multiple instances of process

Tags: apache2, mysql, cpu, swap, background-process

Good day,

I have a VPS server with LAMP setup. As a couple of days I have a huge spike in process and
I don't know how to investigate this cause.

Here is the output of the `htop` command https://ibb.co/PYj1f5X

Comment: That just means your server received a bunch of requests at the same time. It may have been hit by a layer-8 DDoS attack, so you might want to consider Cloudflare. Apache2 needs a process for each connection, up to a default limit of 150, so you should lower that number to something your server can handle. I would disable swap completely, so that the extra connections' processes die instead of slowing down the server

Answer (score -1):

I have to ask:

I have you restarted the VPS :)

Then I would suggested you go through your mysql and apache logs, and also check your sys.log and see if you can identify anything unusual.

Comment: Yes, the only thing that worked via the VPS website panel.

Comment: DId the site come back up? apache and mysql working or?

Comment: Yes, the are working fine now. I revert back the swap from 2GB to 1GB to see if that was the problem. As per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12178235/927287